# Canvas JS using ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, canvas, chart.js

I am using ajax call to get data to populate canvas js stackedbar chart. But it's throwing an error "canvasjs.min.js:102 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined". Below is my code.

```
      <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html>
      <head>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/jquerymin.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var dps = [{x: 1, y: 10}]; 

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {

            title:{
                text:"Olympic Medals of all Times (till 2012 Olympics)"             

            },
                        animationEnabled: true,
                        legend: {
                            cursor:"pointer",
                            itemclick : function(e) {
                              if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                                  e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                              }
                              else {
                                  e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                              }
                              chart.render();
                            }
                          },
                          axisY: {
                              title: "Medals"
                            },
                            toolTip: {
                              shared: true,  
                              content: function(e){
                                var str = '';
                                var total = 0 ;
                                var str3;
                                var str2 ;
                                for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++){
                                    console.log(e.entries[i].dataPoint.y);
                                  var  str1 = "<span style= 'color:"+e.entries[i].dataSeries.color + "'> " + e.entries[i].dataSeries.name + "</span>: <strong>"+  e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + "</strong> <br/>" ; 
                                  total = e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + total;
                                  str = str.concat(str1);
                                }
                                str2 = "<span style = 'color:DodgerBlue; '><strong>"+e.entries[0].dataPoint.label + "</strong></span><br/>";
                                str3 = "<span style = 'color:Tomato '>Total: </span><strong>" + total + "</strong><br/>";

                                return (str2.concat(str)).concat(str3);
                              }

                            },

            data: [
            {     
                type: "bar",
                showInLegend: true,
                name: "Gold",
                color: "gold",              
                dataPoints:dps[0]

            },
            {     
                type: "bar",
                showInLegend: true,
                name: "Silver",
                color: "silver",                
                dataPoints:dps[1]

            },
            {     
                type: "bar",
                showInLegend: true,
                name: "Bronze",
                color: "#A57164",               
                dataPoints:dps[2]

            }

            ]
            });

        $.ajax({

            url : "stackedcanvas.json",
            success : function(result) {
                var dataFromJSON = JSON.parse(result);
            dps.splice(0, dps.length);

            $.each(dataFromJSON, function (index, value) {
            dps.push(value);
            chart.render();
            });


            }



        });
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The json file is here:

```
{
"gold": [{
    "y": 198,
    "label": "Italy"
}, {
    "y": 201,
    "label": "China"
}, {
    "y": 202,
    "label": "France"
}, {
    "y": 236,
    "label": "Great Britain"
}, {
    "y": 395,
    "label": "Soviet Union"
}, {
    "y": 957,
    "label": "USA"
}],
"silver": [{
    "y": 166,
    "label": "Italy"
}, {
    "y": 144,
    "label": "China"
}, {
    "y": 223,
    "label": "France"
}, {
    "y": 272,
    "label": "Great Britain"
}, {
    "y": 319,
    "label": "Soviet Union"
}, {
    "y": 759,
    "label": "USA"
}],
"bronze": [{
    "y": 185,
    "label": "Italy"
}, {
    "y": 128,
    "label": "China"
}, {
    "y": 246,
    "label": "France"
}, {
    "y": 272,
    "label": "Great Britain"
}, {
    "y": 296,
    "label": "Soviet Union"
}, {
    "y": 666,
    "label": "USA"
}]
}
```

I have validated the Json,and it is correct. It gives data in format [Array[6],Array[6],Array[6]]. Please tell me where the issue is, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to parse json retrieved from jquery's ajax method, as it is already parsed.  Other than that, my other guess would be that you have no x property in your json, and the graph code is looking for that x.

Comment: It gives this error- "jquerymin.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '804' in{...}" if I don't parse it.

Comment: I feel like there is some error in-- $.each(dataFromJSON, function (index, value) {
            dps.push(value);
            chart.render();
            });

Answer (score -1):

Got it! Had to make chart inside ajax call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var dps = [{x: 1, y: 10}]; 

$.ajax({

            url : "stackedcanvasjson.json",
            success : function(result) {
                var dataFromJSON = JSON.parse(result);
            dps.splice(0, dps.length);

            $.each(dataFromJSON, function (index, value) {
            dps.push(value);

            });

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {

            title:{
                text:"Olympic Medals of all Times (till 2012 Olympics)"             

            },
                        animationEnabled: true,
                        legend: {
                            cursor:"pointer",
                            itemclick : function(e) {
                              if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                                  e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                              }
                              else {
                                  e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                              }
                              chart.render();
                            }
                          },
                          axisY: {
                              title: "Medals"
                            },
                            toolTip: {
                              shared: true,  
                              content: function(e){
                                var str = '';
                                var total = 0 ;
                                var str3;
                                var str2 ;
                                for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++){
                                    console.log(e.entries[i].dataPoint.y);
                                  var  str1 = "<span style= 'color:"+e.entries[i].dataSeries.color + "'> " + e.entries[i].dataSeries.name + "</span>: <strong>"+  e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + "</strong> <br/>" ; 
                                  total = e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + total;
                                  str = str.concat(str1);
                                }
                                str2 = "<span style = 'color:DodgerBlue; '><strong>"+e.entries[0].dataPoint.label + "</strong></span><br/>";
                                str3 = "<span style = 'color:Tomato '>Total: </span><strong>" + total + "</strong><br/>";

                                return (str2.concat(str)).concat(str3);
                              }

                            },

            data: [
            {     
                type: "bar",
                showInLegend: true,
                name: "CR",
                color: "#1f77b4",               
                dataPoints:dps[0]

            },
            {     
                type: "bar",
                showInLegend: true,
                name: "TR",
                color: "#2ca02c",               
                dataPoints:dps[1]

            },
            {     
                type: "bar",
                showInLegend: true,
                name: "IR",
                color: "#f52887",               
                dataPoints:dps[2]

            },
            {     
                type: "bar",
                showInLegend: true,
                name: "PTR",
                color: "#5afffa",               
                dataPoints:dps[3]

            },
            {     
                type: "bar",
                showInLegend: true,
                name: "WO",
                color: "#9b14e7",               
                dataPoints:dps[4]

            }

            ]
        });



        chart.render();
            }




});

    });
</script>
```